# How can i load a view in opencart from my controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart

in my controller i have done something like this

```
   $this->data['first_name']= $this->request->post['first_name'];
```

now i want to load view

i have done something like this

```
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/considerForm.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/considerForm.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/information/considerForm.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(  
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

and in tpl file

iam simple doing this

```
   <php echo $first_name; ?>
```

but it is showing me blank page.
 am i loading the view correctly??

Comment: I don't know anything about opencart, but frameworks usually have a `view()` method for templates which specifically renders the template, so maybe you try in your php file `$this->template->view()`.

Comment: i think In open cart we cant load view like this anyways let me give it a try .iam a newbie too

Comment: you are using this: $this->request->post['first_name'];  its mean you are enter from some form.

Comment: @YUNOWORK i did some think like this $this->template->view(template/information/considerForm.tpl); and got error Fatal error: Call to a member function view() on a non-object

Comment: also print the header as well, <?php echo $header; ?> now check your header is displayed or not, if displayed then its mean your view is loading properly.

Comment: @RajaUsmanMehmood yes iam initialising it from form in my information

Comment: In OpenCart you do not load any view, you just set variables used in it, specify the template and render it for the output. Your code seems correct to me. If you got blank page probably it's becuase nothing happens until you do a POST request to that page or you have some FATAL error somewhere else. Make sure you have `display_errors` set to 1 and optionally check your PHP error log. If everything is fine, then try to render some more HTML for the output to make sure the content is OK, just nothing to display because of no POST request.

Comment: @RajaUsmanMehmood no its not showing me header aswell

Comment: @shadyyx exactly right em just rendring as well but still the blank page is there p.s there is no error in error log

Comment: @shadyyx even if i echo my name in "ammar" in tpl its still blank i think its not comming to my tpl file

Comment: OK, I think the problem may be here: you check for this path `DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/considerForm.tpl')` but then load only this path: `$this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/considerForm.tpl')` - add `DIR_TEMPLATE` before it...

Comment: @shadyyx Found the problem actually there were two tpl files in same folder which were causing problem deleted one and now working. thanks